# Docker Experimental FeaturesToolbox

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-swarm

Currently I have the normal docker windows toolbox running 1.12.0 (updatable to 1.12.1). I was wondering if it was possible to get a toolbox with the experimental features. Or is it possible to upgrade my current 1.12.0 docker to the experimental version?

Answer (score 0):

There is no experimental toolbox release, but you can download the experimental `docker` windows binary from the releases page: https://github.com/docker/docker/releases/tag/v1.12.1